# C# to run a scheduled task using windows service and xml

Tags: c#, xml, windows-services

```
<Day>
 <Monday>true</Monday>
 <Tuesday>false</Tuesday>
 <Wednesday>true</Wednesday>
 <Thursday>false</Thursday>
 <Friday>true</Friday>
 <Saturday>false</Saturday>
 <Sunday>true</Sunday>
 </Day>
<Time>
 <time>17:18</time>
</Time>
```

I have above xml using which I want to run a specific task through a windows service. For example: The windows service should open notepad at Monday and Sunday 17:18 pm.

Please let me know how can I achieve this in C #. How to create a Windows service and ask that service to look into above XML and start a program whenever the scheduled time and day is reached ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a scheduler like [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) instead of building a bespoke scheduler. It may save you some time and effort.

Note that Quartz.net uses CRON style scheduling syntax, which is different from your XML. But it is still configurable.

Comment: I am bound to use  only XML for scheduling.Please let me know if you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I`ll advise 2 ways:
 1. If the use of XML is not important, then the better way will be to create a windows scheduled task and configure it as you want. After, you can create some console application, which will run by configured schedule.
 2. If XML must be used any way, you can create a windows service which runs every 5 minutes for example. Every time it must read the content of your XML and compare it to the DateTime.Now of your system.

You can find a lot articles in the internet on how to create windows service. For example this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C) from CodeProject describes how to create a Windows service in C#.

I'd recommend [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net) for scheduling. If you're dead set on using a custom XML solution, and you're on .NET 3.5 or later, look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Depending on the program you want the service to execute (i.e. a GUI application like notepad), you may need to consider [Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx) on Vista and later.